# ConfigurationErrorsException when reading app.config setting

Tags: c#, .net

i'm trying to test a page for a webshop, i want to use the API client from mollie.
https://github.com/foxip/mollie-api-csharp#how-to-use-the-api-client
but i have had some problems:

1. i can't test the API client in visualstudio for web
2. When i try to test in in normal visual studio i have some errors:
   in program.cs

   ```
   MollieClient mollieClient = new MollieClient();
   mollieClient.setApiKey(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mollie_api_key"]);
   ```

in the app.config file i find this:

```
<appSettings configSource="localApp.config">
        <add key="mollie_api_key" value="test_1234" />
</appSettings>
```

for obvious reasons i changed my API key to a fake key, but this code gives an error, it can't find the key and its value a simple solution i found was:

```
MollieClient mollieClient = new MollieClient();
mollieClient.setApiKey("Test_1234");
```

3. This works, the console shows me loading issuers... but it gives an error here;

   ```
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
   ```

i get an `ConfigurationErrorsException`, i figured that the value of request is null and that is what i think causes the problem

but the following line should fix that problem doesn't it?

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Proxy"]))
{
    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Proxy"]));
    request.Proxy = proxy;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately we can't know what errors you're experiencing if you don't include them in your question.

Comment: sorry, i'll edit it !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me you mistakenly added the [`configSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute. That attribute forces reading the settings from an external file, a file you probably don't have. Also, the correct syntax for this element is `file`, as you can find in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms228154%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on `appSettings`.

That will be the reason for the exception. Remove the `configSource` and you will be fine.

Comment: thanks alot this solves the problem.
How can but how can implement this in my website since i can't use it in web developer

Comment: You can use the `web.config` for web projects and read it using the `WebConfigurationManager`.

Comment: i added the mollie.cs the app.config and the program.cs file and the properties map, i noticed when i open the mollie.cs file and the program.cs in the web developer that alot of code is red underlined, when i go over it with my mouse its says: `the type or namespace name "..." could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `as far as i know i have a file assemblyInfo.cs in properties

Comment: Did you add the `System.Configuration` assembly and `using` statement?

Comment: when i look at the program.cs file i find this at the top:
`using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Configuration;`

Comment: Seems okay. Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: since i cant upload pictures yet, i have a link with a picture of the problem this might help solving it
http://i61.tinypic.com/2461hs1.png

Comment: You don't have the service classes generated and you are using a Program class inside a web app, that is not possible. This is getting massively off-topic. Please post a new question if you can't get it working.